# Помогите решить, из-за чего может быть данная ошибка Missing Permissions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Данная ошибка вылетает сама по себе грубо говоря, даже когда команды не используются и бот грубо говоря находится в покое, но ошибка постоянно и назойливо каждые 5-15 секунд вылетает. Полная содержание ошибки:

```
(node:9176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at item.request.gen.end (F:\bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (F:\bots\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:9176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:9176) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Данный код мне присылает эту ошибку постоянно:

```js
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM scores WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"`).then(row => {
         if (!row) {
           sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, points, level) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [message.author.id, 1, 0]);
     } else {
           let curLevel = Math.floor(1 * Math.sqrt(row.points + 1));
           if (curLevel > row.level) {
             row.level = curLevel;
             sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET points = ${row.points + 1}, level = ${row.level} WHERE userId = ${message.author.id}`);
             message.reply(`Вы повысили свой уровень до **${curLevel}**!`);
           }
           sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET points = ${row.points + 1} WHERE userId = ${message.author.id}`);
         }
        }).catch(() => {
         console.error;
         sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, points INTEGER, level INTEGER)").then(() => {
           sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, points, level) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [message.author.id, 1, 0]);
         });
       });
```

Comment: Начни с того, что у тебя где-то не стоит `.catch` на промисе, а дальше залогируй и отправь сюда нормальный стэк ошибки.

Comment: @Shiki, Я нашел какой код мне выдаёт постоянно данную ошибку, это система лвл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как ошибка `DiscordAPIError`, следовательно она возникает при вызове какого-то метода, связанным именно с дискордом.

Идем дальше: сама ошибка - `Missing Permission`, которая означает, что при выполнении какого-либо метода у бота недостаточно прав для того, чтобы выполнить действие (методом исключения - отправить сообщение в канал)

А теперь исправляем:

```js
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM scores WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"`).then(row => {
         if (!row) {
           sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, points, level) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [message.author.id, 1, 0]);
     } else {
           let curLevel = Math.floor(1 * Math.sqrt(row.points + 1));
           if (curLevel > row.level) {
             row.level = curLevel;
             sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET points = ${row.points + 1}, level = ${row.level} WHERE userId = ${message.author.id}`);
             // Добавляем .catch(), чтобы не высылать сообщение
             message.reply(`Вы повысили свой уровень до **${curLevel}**!`)
             .catch(() => {
               // Действие при ошибке (я просто зануляю функцию)
               return;
             });
           }
           sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET points = ${row.points + 1} WHERE userId = ${message.author.id}`);
         }
        }).catch(() => {
         console.error;
         sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, points INTEGER, level INTEGER)").then(() => {
           sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, points, level) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [message.author.id, 1, 0]);
         });
       });
```